# Closure of a set-Why is every set contained in a smallest closed set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

I was reading the book [Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra and Differential Forms- A Unified Approach by John and Barbara Hubbard](https://www.amazon.ca/Vector-Calculus-Linear-Algebra-Differential/dp/0136574467), but I am unable to correctly understand the concept of a closure of a set.

The book defines closure as-

> Definition 1.5.8 (Closure). If $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the closure of $A$ is the set of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that **for all** $r>0$ , $B_r(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset$

Note the "for all". To me it means that all the points in the closure must lie in A or its boundary, if not there exists an open ball of radius $\epsilon>0$ s.t its intersection with $A$ is the empty set.

In a previous paragraph it also says,

> Every set is contained in a smallest closed set, called its closure.

Here is my confusion -

Consider the set $\{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2<9\}$ to be $A$

According to the definiton, isn't $\{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x^2+y^2 \leq 2\}$ a closure of $A$. Similarly any arbritary disk of radius less than 9 fits in the definiton of closure. Clearly they do not contain all of $A$ and I can build smaller and smaller disks.
Why then did the author say the closure of $A$ is the *smallest* closed set to *contain* $A$ ?

I seem to be misunderstanding something crucial here and I'd like to ask if anyone be kind enough to tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The closure you gave for the set A you considered is not the closure of A because it does not contain all of A.

Comment: I think you’re omitting the “containing $A$”. The disk of radius 2 doesn’t contain your $A$, so it can’t be the closure of $A$. They mean that the smallest closed set **containing $A$** is the closure of $A$. To see this, let $S$ be the collection of all closed sets containing $A$. Then $\bigcap S$ is the desired smallest such closed set.

Comment: @WilliamElliot but the definition of closure provided does not impose it to contain all of A. It just says that it should contain some part of A , i.e  its intersection with A should be non-empty.

Comment: @MPW I could not reply to you in the previous comment.

Comment: @RahulKumar Definition does say it must contain $A$ because $(\forall a\in A) (\forall r>0) a\in B_r(a)\cap A \implies (\forall a\in A) (\forall r>0) B_r(a)\cap A\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: How did we get the first "for all' clause ( $\forall a \in A$)? The definition said for $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ right ?

Comment: No, it doesn’t say that—the ball isn’t the closure. It says that points that ARE in the closure are characterized by the fact that every neighborhood of such a point must meet $A$. The balls are only utilities to test various points for membership in the closure of $A$. The collection of ALL points with this property constitutes the closure of $A$. It should be immediately obvious that every point of $A$ satisfies this property and so is in the closure of $A$. But there may be other points in the closure of $A$ as well (they will be exactly the rest of the boundary of $A$).

Comment: @RahulKumar What I've written is not the definition, it's a statement that is true. Definition you've written is the definition. What I've written is that for all $a\in A$ it is true that $(\forall r>0) a\in B_r(a) \cap A$. This is trivial and really easy to see. Take any set $A$ and it will be true. That statement then implies that for all $a\in A$ it is true that $(\forall r>0) B_r(a) \cap A\neq \emptyset$. This explicitly gives us that every $ a\in A $ satisfies the definition of an element of $clA$ that you've given. Therefore $A\subset clA$.

Comment: @MPW I understand that the ball isn't the closure, its only for testing whether or not the point centered around the ball is part of the closure set. But for all points in any subset of A, their open balls satisfy the condition to constitute those set of points as a closure for A. I cannot understand why the ball must contain all of A, I don't see that in the definition. Thank you so much for taking the time to reply.

Comment: Nowhere does it say that the ball must contain $A$. YOU said that. It isn’t true. It’s THE CLOSURE OF $A$ that must contain $A$.

Comment: Again, note that you should only be looking at closed sets which contain $A$. The smallest *of these sets* is called the closure of $A$. Sets which don’t already contain $A$, as well as sets which are not closed, are not candidates—they don’t meet the criteria for being considered.

Comment: @MPW I understand now what you were trying to explain. thank you so much for the help. the issue was in my confusion in comprehending that it must have ALL points with that property and not just some.

Comment: Notice the $\neq \emptyset$. I literally nearly typed your question verbatim into another post and noticed two things 1. Your identical question to mine and 2. The not equal to the empty set when I was reading it as equal to the empty set! Not sure if that distinction helps. I had the same intuition that the part you bolded must be wrong before I noticed that. When you walk along the fence, an arbitrarily small ball (all r over 0) should still touch the enclosed set, otherwise you could get closer, so you are not a closure (closure is smallest such fence).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me use the shorter notation $B_r(p)$ for an open ball (open disk) of radius $r$ centered at $p$.

You are asserting that $B_2(0)$ fills the bill to be the closure of $B_9(0)$.  That's not true.  Consider the point $x = (0,3)$, which is in $B_9(0)$.  For every $r > 0$, $B_r(x)$ contains at least one point of $B_9(0)$ - for instance, $B_r(x)$ contains $x$ itself.  The closure of $B_9(0)$ was defined to be the set of all points having that property, so $x$ has to be an element of the closure.  But $x$ is not in $B_2(0)$.  So $B_2(0)$ cannot be the closure of $B_9(0)$.

This logic shows that the closure of any set has to be a *superset* of that set.

Comment: Closure of $A$ is the set $\{a\in\Bbb{R^n}|(\forall r>0) B_r(a)\cap A \neq \emptyset\}$. Am I right in saying it is a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the property that an open ball centered at each point of the set with any radius, must contain some portion of A? If so, doesn't each and every point in $B_2(0)$ satisfy this property?

Comment: @RahulKumar: Yes.  But that notation requires the closure to be the set of ALL such points - every point having the property must be an elements of the closure.  Although every point in $B_2(0)$ has the property, there are other points with the property that are not in $B_2(0)$ (like $(3,0)$).  Therefore $B_2(0)$ is not the set of ALL the points having that property.

Comment: "The closure of 9(0) was defined to be the set of all points having that property, so  has to be an element of the closure."

Can you tell me how we inferred this ? How did you come to know it must contain the set of ALL points with the property. To me it just seems like it should get any point of the property, not necessarily all.

Comment: @RahulKumar: This is the definition of [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate).  When I write $A = \{x \in B : P(x)\}$, this means, by definition, that $A$ should consist of ALL the points $x \in B$ for which the statement $P(x)$ is true, and only those points.  In other words, $x$ must be in $A$ **if and only if** $x$ is an element of $B$ for which $P(x)$ is true.  You seem to be missing the "if" and only seeing the "only if".

Comment: Wow. I'm sorry for the trouble. I don't know why I didn't see that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}|x^2+y^2\leq2\}$ doesn't fit the definition of closure for $A=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb{R^2}|x^2+y^2<9\}$ because it doesn't contain all $a\in \Bbb{R^2}$ that satisfy: $(\forall r>0)\ B_r(a)\cap A \neq \emptyset$.

Closure of $A$ is set $clA=\{a\in\Bbb{R^n}|(\forall r>0) B_r(a)\cap A \neq \emptyset\}$, not $clA\subset \{a\in\Bbb{R^n}|(\forall r>0) B_r(a)\cap A \neq \emptyset\}$

This part is true: "Note the "for all". To me it means that all the points in the closure must lie in A or its boundary, if not there exists an open ball of radius $\epsilon>0$ s.t its intersection with $A$ is the empty set."

Comment: The disk of radius 2 is a subset of the open disk of radius 9. So shouldn't the open balls of r>0 centered at every point in the disk of radius 2 contain some part of A (if not all)?

Comment: @RahulKumar They should and they do, which gives us that disk of radius 2 is SUBSET of closure (of open disk of radius 9), but it's not EQUAL to closure. Closure contains more elements. Closure of any disk of radius r is closed disk of radius r.